# Monitoring Private Network Website Uptime

Tags: php, javascript, web

I've been tasked with developing a website that can monitor or poll the status of several of our client's websites. Several of the websites are only accessible through VPN, so web-based services are out.

My supervisor mentioned an "old school" method wherein the website would be divided into iframes that loaded each page. While this method would most likely work and serve our needs, I feel as if it's not the best or most appropriate way to handle this.

Additionally, I won't be able to install anything on the servers I'm monitoring. I'm imagining something like http://isup.me on a local machine with VPN access that refreshes periodically so we know a website is down before the client.

Is anyone aware of a way that I could implement monitoring that meets the above criteria?

---

UPDATE: After looking into the current state of the iframe tag in HTML5, and noting that it is not deprecated, I went ahead and moved forward implementing that solution. It's certainly not the most robust solution, however it meets the client's needs and was quick and simple to implement.

Thanks to those that offered possible solutions.

Comment: nagios and a vpn_plugin http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-and-Systems-Management/check_vpn/details

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `HEAD` `XmlHttpRequest` to check the availability, I guess the iframe is not intended to *show* the website?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to install [munin](http://www.munin-monitoring.org) on the server that does the monitoring?
All it does is calling command line scripts every 5m inutes and make those charts with the results.

You can write nobrainer-php scripts that echo the result of a file_get_content.

(In case you are not familiar with php on command line: navigate into the folder, enter "php myfile.php" and see all echoes on the console.)

I would return the loading time in ms.

As for the VPN - I understand that your mashine is already connected to the others? In that case VPN shall be transparent with no need for further consideration.

Check (e.g. Puttys) port forwarding, if vpn is a problem.